# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, exception, build.gradle

I am facing this issue when I try to build my Flutter Project.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_string_encryption'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)

And when i opened my Gradle file at Project Level then GradleException Function hilighted giving error of can't Resolve symbol.Here is my Gradle File Code.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()  //Here Error of Properties can't resolve
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
//Here is error of GradleException Can't resolve on below line
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hbr.food_delivery_admin_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Please help me how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove new keyword before GradleException.

```
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

and also please avoid asking this question, it's already all over stackoverflow.